# Could it be argued that the set containing only the origin is a "vector space"?

Tags: vector-spaces

From the axioms I remember about vector spaces that are included on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), it seems that the origin itself could be called a vector space. I think traditionally its thought of as the smallest subspace (and a rather boring one) but I'm curious to know if I can claim that its a vector space strictly based off the definition of vector space.

Comment: Yes. The trivial space is that which only contains the zero vector.

Comment: Yes, it is vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the zero vector space. It satisfies all of the axioms, as you can check for yourself. A nice exercise is to compute its dimension and in particular to verify explicitly that all of its bases have the same size. (This will require being very clear about the definitions of linear independence and of spanning.)

Comment: I’d be down to spend more time thinking about it if you want to help me think through some of those problems. Seems like the dim would be 0 since it can’t spam anything beyond whatever the 0 element in the space is. I’m also not sure what’s meant by “all its bases” because it seems like it only has one bases.... itself. Can anything be linear independent in this space? Well.. Maybe you could argue 1 but I think 0 since it can’t “span” anything other than itself.

Comment: @financial_physician: yes, the dimension is $0$, and yes, there's only one basis, but it's not $\{ 0 \}$. If this were a basis it would have one element which would make the dimension $1$. And in fact $\{ 0 \}$ is not linearly independent, because a nontrivial linear combination of it, namely $1 \cdot 0$, is equal to $0$. The only basis is the empty set $\emptyset$, and this is the only answer consistent with it having dimension $0$. The tricky thing is to understand in what sense the empty set is linearly independent and spans $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: As I understand it, something is linear independence needs to be thought of us as comparing one thing to a set of other things. Can my thing be expressed as a linear combination of those other things? If so, than my thing is not linearly independent of those things. It does seem strange to argue the empty set can span a non-empty set... I'd love to hear the explanation. I'm not sure if I can get much further than what I've said here haha

Comment: Like you'd have to argue that $\alpha \cdot \emptyset = 0$ for all $\alpha$ but since the empty set isn't a number nor does it contain any numbers, I'm not sure how you'd get there.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that $\cdot$ is ill-defined in this context. You'd have to make up your own definition.

Comment: @financial_physician: there is a subtlety here but if you don't deal with this subtlety you can't assign the zero vector space a dimension. There is an "empty linear combination" with no terms which produces $0$. This is a slight variant of an empty sum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum Once you know that, it straightforwardly follows that the span of $\emptyset$ is $\{ 0 \}$ (in any vector space). Linear dependence is still a bit trickier. It says that if a linear combination of the vectors is zero then the coefficients must be zero. But the only linear combination possible is empty.

Comment: An alternative definition of linear independence and spanning can make things a bit clearer. A set of vectors $v_1, \dots v_n \in V$ in a vector space (a finite set for simplicity) defines a linear map $k^n \to V$ given by taking linear combinations. The $v_i$ are linearly independent iff this map is injective and span iff this map is surjective. When $n = 0$ this map is just the inclusion $0 \to V$.

Comment: Yet another definition of the span of a collection of vectors, which generalizes to other algebraic structures, is that $\text{span}(v_1, v_2, \dots )$ is the intersection of all subspaces containing the $v_i$ (it's a nice exercise to prove this is equivalent to the definition in terms of linear combinations). So the span of an empty set is the intersection of all subspaces, which is $\{ 0 \}$.